# Node request data from API, push data to array. Then run another request using that new array

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loops, request

```
var UfcAPI = require('ufc-api');

var ufc = new UfcAPI({
    version: '3'
});

const fighterId = [];

function getFighterId() {
    ufc.fighters(function(err, res) {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.body.length; i++) {
            fighterId.push(res.body[i].id);
        }
        // console.log(fighterId);
    })
};

function allFighters() {
    for (let j = 0; j < fighterId.length; j++) {
        request("http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/us/fighters/" + fighterId[j] + ".json", function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    }
};
```

The first function getFighterId() will look through the json for all fighters on the UFC roster. I capture all Ids of each fighter and push it to the fighterId array. Then i want to do a loop querying fighters with their id to get more detailed info on each fighter.

I understand that I need the array to completely get filled then run my second function. I found info on promises and Async but super confused on how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: does `ufc.fighters` return `promises` @Nate

Comment: @saikat-hajra ```ufc.fighters``` is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ufc-api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var UfcAPI = require('ufc-api');

var ufc = new UfcAPI({
    version: '3'
});

function allFighters(fighterIds) {
    fighterIds.forEach(fighterId => {
        request("http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/us/fighters/" + fighterId + ".json", function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            }
        })
    });
};

function getFighterId(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        ufc.fighters((err,res)=>{
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res.body)
        })

    })

}

getFighterId()
.then((ufcData)=>ufcData.map((u)=>u.id))
.then((data)=>allFighters(data))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Please try with this one I have implemented with Promises. it can be implemented in many more ways. Let me know if it helps you.